# sshd_config file configuration

Tags: linux, ssh

```
# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
```

Can anyone explain what happens if we comment all the above hostkeys.

Comment: -1 that is an extremely misleading question. I have checked the defaults for openssh, and every single one of the HostKey and HostKeys lines are already commented out and in exactly the format you have given. Also, clearly, the commented out lines in the file just demonstrate the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

So on a test system I removed all `HostKey` the lines from my `sshd_config`.  Then killed the current sshd process and started it manually in debug mode with `sshd -d`.

The sshd daemon on my distribution appears to be be smart enough to attempt to read the keys under `/etc/ssh/` if they have standard file names.  Even if you don't reference them with a `HostKey` directive.

But if you remove those lines **and** delete all the existing host keys, then you will not be able to connect with a remote client.

HostKeys config removed, keys deleted from `/etc/ssh`.

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key': No such file or directory
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key': No such file or directory
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key': No such file or directory
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
# incoming client connection
Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 44636
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 101/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types:  [preauth]
No supported key exchange algorithms [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 45384
```

So to explain what is happening.  OpenSSH appears to have some hard coded defaults for Hostkeys.  If you don't provide any Hostkeys configuration, it will look for files at the standard location.  If it cannot find any, then it will still start, but no incoming connections will be possible.

Comment: well yes it has defaults, but the sshd_config file in openssh has those lines commented out by default anyway.  And if you look at the default ssh_config file you see that every single line is commented out. So clearly the commented out lines just show what the default is.